# Set Certificate PrivateKey Permissions in .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, x509certificate2, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I had a requirement where I need to set permissions for the Certificate private key, I used below method (**SetCertificatePrivateKeyPermissions**) which was working fine with **.Net framework 4.7.2** but now I had to migrate the project framework to **.Net 5**, Because of this project framework upgradation this existing code is breaking.

RSACryptoServiceProvider and CspParameters  classes refers to System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll (C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll), with this dll reference I am facing 2 issues with the existing code

1. During the conversion of certificate.PrivateKey to RSACryptoServiceProvider it is returning NULL.
2. While creating an instance of CspParameters I am not able to assign the CryptoKeySecurity value from rsa as this property is not available/supported in both RSACryptoServiceProvider and CspParameters classes of .NET 5 while it was supported in .NET 4.7.2 version.

Please let me know how to handle this issue ? or is there any alternative solution where I can set permissions for the Certificate private key in .NET 5 ?

Code snippet:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public static void SetCertificatePrivateKeyPermissions(X509Certificate2 certificate, IdentityReference account, Operation operation)
{
  var rsa = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
  if (rsa != null)//ISSUE 1: rsa is NULL
  {
    var cspParams = new CspParameters(rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName, rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName)
    {
      Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey | CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,
      CryptoKeySecurity = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity//ISSUE 2: There is no CryptoKeySecurity property present
    };

    switch (operation)
    {
      case Operation.Add:
        cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity.AddAccessRule(new CryptoKeyAccessRule(account, CryptoKeyRights.GenericRead, AccessControlType.Allow));
        break;
      case Operation.Remove:
        cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new CryptoKeyAccessRule(account, CryptoKeyRights.GenericAll, AccessControlType.Allow));
        break;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentException("Unhandled operation type");
    }

    using (var rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
    {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no ".NET 5 Framework". There is only .NET 5.

Answer (score 4):

.NET 5 doesn't have `CryptoKeySecurity`, because it is Windows-specific and hasn't ported yet (if ever planned to port). Couple words on your issues:

1. `var rsa = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;` -- this construction can be considered obsolete and deprecated since .NET Framework 4.6. Under no condition you should use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` if you are on 4.6+. Instead, you should access [X509Certificate2 class extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-5.0#extension-methods) only to retrieve public/private key handles. More details in my blog post: [Accessing and using certificate private keys in .NET Framework/.NET Core](https://www.pkisolutions.com/accessing-and-using-certificate-private-keys-in-net-framework-net-core/).
2. When using `X509Certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey()` extension method on Windows, it will return an instance of `RSACng` class that contains [Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacng.key?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_RSACng_Key) property which is of type [CngKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey?view=net-5.0). Then use [GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey.getproperty?view=net-5.0) and [SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey.setproperty?view=net-5.0) methods to read and write `Security Descr` property. You can check for `Security Descr Support` property if key supports ACL (1 if supports, any other value means the key doesn't support ACL).

Comment: FYI if the CngKey is stored with the `Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider` using the FileSecurity/FileSystemAccessRule will work just fine, as the key is stored as a file. I've just done that with a net5 app using the code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51028524/682203)

Comment: When I tested out this solution on Windows, while running with administrative privileges, I got a `CryptographicException`, trying to look up `Security Descr` or `Security Descr Support` properties. Even if these properties did return a result, I don't see how this answer explains show to change the permissions of the ACL?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the container name, and then based on that determine the full path to the file and apply the account permissions:

```
private static void SetupFileSecurity(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    var privateKey = RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(certificate);
    var rsaCngKey = privateKey as RSACng;
    if (rsaCngKey == null)
        throw new Exception("Expecting RSA CNG key.");
    var cngKey = rsaCngKey.Key;
    var keyName = cngKey.UniqueName;
    if (keyName == null)
        throw new Exception("The key cannot be ephemeral.");
    var keysDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), @"Microsoft\Crypto\Keys");
    var filePath = Path.Combine(keysDirectory, keyName);
    AddFileSystemPermissions(account, filePath, FileSystemRights.FullControl);
}
```

This worked well as a test, but I'd be cautious for anything else.